# what's wrong with my xml formatting?

Tags: xml, vb.net

can someone please tell me why this xml formatting is incorrect and why my vb.net application does not want to read it?

http://sites.google.com/site/shadchanproject/Home/lots1.xml

is it OK to have an apostrophe between the tags? my vb debugger is saying:
Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 33, position 10. (this is where i put the apostrophe)

Comment: encode apostrophes. (and angle brackets, etc.)
use "&apos;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You can not expect to close a node with a tag with a different name.  Your opening element tag is "7190" and your closing element tag is "7191".  They should be the same.</strike>

Plus:[edit: missed tags on reading]

XML elements must follow these naming rules:

1. Names can contain letters, numbers,
   and other characters
2. **Names cannot
   start with a number or punctuation
   character**
3. Names cannot start with
   the letters xml (or XML, or Xml,
   etc)
4. Names cannot contain spaces

Comment: I think you misread the XML. It's well formed wrt to balanced tags. Correct about the numeric starting char of the element name.

Comment: @spender: thanks for the heads-up.  You are correct - I missed the closing and opening tags in the middle of the xml on first reading.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

XML elements cannot begin with digits.  You should try to [stick with just letters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar).  Prefix it with some extra data if you need to, to get it to be valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is because you are using numbers for your element names. Try prefixing these with another character, and it should parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a tag that start with a number, see [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Names).

substitute 7190 and 7191 tags with, for example, _7190 and _7191 and your xml will bi well formed

Answer (score 0):

Is the file static or being generated dynamically?  Something in the download causes the content to be truncated...

EDIT:

Actually; I downloaded the xml and it looks fine.
I did notice the use of unescaped quotes though.

Do you need to replace the ' with &#39;  ?

Comment: I got the point... my original response didn't actually account for a raw get of the source.  In addition to the numeric tag names needing to change, I think escaping the quotes may be a good idea too.  Please undo the downvote ;)

Comment: I did actually do view source, but chrome choked.  I had to use powershell to actually download the source (in place of wget)